# Read all data from socket

Tags: java, sockets, asynchronous

I want read all data ,synchronously , receive from client or server without `readline()` method in java(like `readall()` in c++).
I don't want use something like code below:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new inputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
String line = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
     document.append(line + "\n");
```

What method should i use?

Comment: What's your objection to using the code you posted?

Comment: Why do you want to get all the data? A common confusion about using Sockets is the assumption it supports receiving of messages and if you can read all the data at once, you can read one whole "message".  While this can appear to work in TCP under low load with time between "messages", TCP doesn't support this and this doesn't work reliably esp under load.  If you need message based protocol, you could try SCTP in Java 7, or use TCP the way it was intended, as a streaming protocol.

Comment: something like browser never send null wile connected and waiting for responding... i want read all headers and data at once and synchronously!

Comment: @Erfan13 Please try again. I can't make head or tail of that gibberish.

Answer (score 6):

If you know the size of incoming data you could use a method like :

```
public int read(char cbuf[], int off, int len) throws IOException;
```

where cbuf is Destination buffer.

**Otherwise**, you'll have to read lines or read bytes. Streams aren't aware of the size of incoming data. The can only sequentially read until end is reached (read method returns -1)

refer here [streams doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/streams.html)

sth like that:

```
public static String readAll(Socket socket) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        sb.append(line).append("\n");
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: I've given you example since there is one more important thing to note: you should be using StringBuilder instead of concatting strings.

Comment: +1 Note: this will read all the characters,  If there are incomplete multi-byte characters, it will be kept in the buffer and will appear later.

Comment: @Tala, Use of StringBuilder for regular concatenations is obsolete at obsolete java optimization tips as well as at java urban myths.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this:

```
   public static String readToEnd(InputStream in) throws IOException {
      byte[] b = new byte[1024];
      int n;
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      while ((n = in.read(b)) >= 0) {
         sb.append(b);
      }
      return sb.toString();
   }
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
public static String readToEnd(InputStream in) throws IOException {
    return new String(in.readAllBytes(),StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
}
```